# Unable to send http post with credentials to iis node server

Tags: node.js, angular, express, iis, cors

I'm trying to send a http post request from my angular app to my node.js server with user credentials in order to log it.
Both are hosted in IIS (the node server with nodeiis) and both are configured to be authenticated by windows authentication.

My angular code:

```
var url = "http://myurl:15001/addItem";
this.http.post(url, {
    "itemName": "SomeName",
    "itemColor": "SomeColor"
}, {withCredentials: true}).subscribe(res =>{
    console.log("Great, item was added");
})
```

My Node.js Code:

```
var app = express();
var allowCrossDomain = function (req, res, next){
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "http://myurl") //Cannot be a wildcard because of the credentials.
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');

if(res.method == 'OPTIONS')
    res.send(200);
else
    next();
};
app.use(allowCrossDomain);

app.post('/addItem', function(req, res){
    //Saves the item...

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://myurl')
    res.status(200);
    res.send(true);
});
```

When I do the request I get the following error to the console:

> OPTIONS http://myurl:15001/addItem 401(Unauthorized)
>
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myurl:15001/addItem. Response to
>   preflight doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://myurl' is therefore bot allowed access. The
>   response had HTTP status code 401.

When I try to do the same thing with my http get request everything works properly and I get the result.
I don't know why my OPTIONS request is unauthorized when I send 200 code for every OPTIONS request.

I tried to use cors node.js package but it didn't help, maybe I didn't used that right.

Could someone explain me how can I solve this and make my http post pass the preflight? Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference Microsoft has IIS CORS module for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular 6, it supports proxy.conf which will proxy the Backend API URL. For more details, here is the link  https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md

Comment: Do you know any other way to solve that without proxy?